# Display different checkboxes based on time of day

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

Hi all just wondering if its possible to display different checkboxes based on the current time. I'm building a medication reminder application, so the application will display different medication the user should take based on the current time. So for example at 1pm the checkboxes might displayed "medication A", "medication C". And at 9pm the checkbox might display "medication B".

This is what I have at the moment, but as you can see it will display the same checkboxes regardless of what the current time is.

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="Med A" value="A">Medication A<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Med B" value="B">Medication B<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Med C" value="C">Medication C<br>
<input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="validate()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the hour and set display when the page loads.

JS:

```
var hour = (new Date()).getHours();

showMed('A', hour == 13);
showMed('B', hour == 21);
showMed('C', hour == 13);

function showMed(med, show) {
    document.getElementById('med' + med).style.display = show ? '' : 'none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<div id='medA'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Med A" value="A">Medication A
</div>
<div id='medB'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Med B" value="B">Medication B
</div>
<div id='medC'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Med C" value="C">Medication C
</div>
</form>
```

You might want to use javascript's setInterval to run the test function every once in a while so if the page is already loaded and the hour changes your page/view will update.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3v3njq2/2/

Comment: I like how you're validating the hour and passing a bool to the function rather than within the function.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!